# Turning off animation in dojox.widget.Dialog

Tags: widget, dojo

Anyone know how to turn animation off in dojox.widget.Dialog? I love the modal dialog, but want it to pop up immediately, rather than the painfully slow animate on that it does. I tried turning off the apparent animation controls, but it still animates. Also looked into the src code, but didn't see any smoking guns for a configuration option. here's the sample invocation:

```
id    = "dojoModalWrapper" 
jsId   = "dojoModalWrapper"
dojoType  = "dojox.widget.Dialog" 
showTitle  = "false" 
dimensions  = "[678,370]" 
sizeDuration = 0
easing   = null
style   = "background-color: #e86d0d; display:none;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [dijit.Dialog](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html)?